# Why is $\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-t+2k\pi\right) = -\sin(t)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, parametric, cycloid

Why is this true?  $$\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-t+2k\pi\right) = -\sin(t)$$

Comment: Hint:  If $k$ is an integer (you don't say so), then the left hand side simplifies (since cosine is periodic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice, $\cos x$ has a period $2\pi$ hence, $\cos(2k \pi+\theta)=\cos \theta$ ($k$ is any integer) & $\cos(\pi+\theta)=-\cos\theta$,

Now, we have $$\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-t+2k \pi\right)=\cos\left(2k\pi+\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-t\right)\right)$$
$$=\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-t\right)$$
$$=\cos\left(\pi+\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right)\right)$$
$$=-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right)$$
$$=-\sin(t)$$

Comment: Not seeing what you did on the last step.  I know $cos(x) = sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $sin(x)=cos(x-\frac{\pi}{2})$

Comment: Note that in the last step: $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)=\sin (x)$

Comment: I also know that cos(x) is even, and sin(x) is odd.  So cos(-x) = cos(x) and sin(-x) = -sin(x).  Does that come into play?

Comment: Ok, I think even/odd doesn't matter, you're just using the phase shift definition to do that last step.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Considering odd/even does not matter because $$\cos\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)=\sin (x)$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is a geometrical interpretation :

The angle between the blue line and the $x$-axis denotes the angle $t$, whose $\sin$ is positive.

The cosine of $3π/2 - t$ (which is negative in this case) can be read thanks to the red line.

You can see that $\cos(3π/2 - t)=-\sin(t)$ may be true, looking at such a picture. This can be helpful then to prove your statement, as it is shown in the other answer.

[image: angle]